# How to specify that only relevant properties will be assigned to a class instance?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that takes in an object (`DataObject`) and uses some of its properties to instantiate a class.

To know which items from the data object should be assigned to which property in the class I use mappings in the form of a list of tuples. The first item in the tuple is the key in the data object and the second is the property name in the class.

```
interface DataObject<T> {
  [name: string]: T[keyof T];
}

// list of mappings
type MappingsList<T> = [string, keyof T][];

// function that instantiates a class and assigns its properties
// from the data object using the mapping from `mappings`
function AttrConstructor<T>(
  ItemClass: { new (): T },
  mappings: MappingsList<T>,
  dataObj: DataObject<T>
) {
  const instance = new ItemClass();
  mappings.forEach(([fromLabel, toLabel]) => {
    instance[toLabel] = dataObj[fromLabel];
  });

  return instance;
}
```

This works well on its own, but the problem arises when I specify that the `dataObject` contains the properties and values for more than one class.

```
class Class1 {
  Prop1a: string;
  Prop1b: number;
}
class Class2 {
  Prop2a: string;
  Prop2b: number;
}

declare const row: DataObject<Class1 & Class2>;

const mappings1: MappingsList<Class1> = [["prop1a", "Prop1a"]];

const makeNew1 = (row: DataObject<Class1>) =>
  AttrConstructor(Class1, mappings1, row);

const instance1 = makeNew1(row);
```

Then I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'DataObject<Class1 & Class2>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DataObject<Class1>'.
  Type 'Class1' is not assignable to type 'Class1 & Class2'.
    Type 'Class1' is not assignable to type 'Class2'.
      Property 'Prop2a' is missing in type 'Class1'.
```

My question is how can I specify that it's ok if the `dataObject` contains more properties than are needed for the current class because the `AttrConstructor` function will make sure only the properties relevant to each class are assigned?

---

**PS**: when putting together this code sample from my real code I actually got no errors at all until I saved the file so maybe my tsconfig.json might be relevant here:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "pretty": true,
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make `DataObject<T>` a `type` and not an `interface`?

Comment: @jcalz well... that seems to have cleared the error... Could you explain why this did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition and mine is that both `DataObject<Class1>` and `DataObject<Class2>` should be structurally identical to `{[k: string]: string | number}`.  And they are, but TypeScript is apparently unable to recognize that the former is identical to the latter.  I'm not 100% sure why this happened, but my guess is that TypeScript is not analyzing the `DataObject<T>` interface deeply enough before deciding that the two types are incompatible.  It likely has decided that, since `DataObject<T>` depends on both `T` and `keyof T` in a property value position, the type should be *invariant in `T`*, meaning that `DataObject<T>` and `DataObject<U>` are only compatible if `T` and `U` are identical.  Normally this is reasonable behavior, but `DataObject<T>` intentionally throws away some of its dependence on `T`, so TypeScript misses the structrual equivalence here. ( You may want to [file a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about this, unless there is already one there... couldn't find a relevant one yet. )

---

One way to deal with this is to change `interface DataObject<T> {...}` to `type DataObject<T> = {...}`.  That's because a type alias isn't a new type but a name for an existing type.  And therefore when faced with `DataObject<Class1 & Class2>` versus `DataObject<Class1>`, the compiler reduces each of them to `{[k: string]: string | number}` right at the outset, and therefore your code will compile as intended.

Another way to deal with this is to change the definition to something like `interface DataObject<P> {[k: string]: P}`, define `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]`, and then use `DataObject<ValueOf<Class1>>` and `DataObject<ValueOf<Class1 & Class2>>` instead of `DataObject<Class1>` and `DataObject<Class1 & Class2>`.  The compiler's heuristics of how `DataObject<P>` depends on `P` will now be accurate.  You might not like this, though, because it forces you to change how you use `DataObject<T>`.

If you need to use the existing interface, there are probably other workarounds.  One possibility is to make a function which converts `DataObject<T>` to `DataObject<U>` if they are structurally compatible.  Something like:

```
type Id<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}
function cast<T, U>(x: U & (Id<U> extends Id<T> ? U : never)): T {
  return x as any as T;
}
const instance1 = makeNew1(cast(row)); // works, maybe?
```

which relies on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), a feature introduced in TypeScript v2.8.  The idea there is that `cast()` will convert from a `T` to a `U` as long as `U` extends `T` in a structural way.

---

Okay, that's all I can think of for now.  Hope it helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this really in-depth answer! Are there any more resources available for learning in detail about type constraints?
Because I've never seen anything as complex as your `x: U & (Id<U> extends Id<T> ? U : never)`, nor would I be able come up with something like that on my own.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I didn't mention that it uses the new conditional types feature (edited above with a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types)).  I'm not sure if there's a great single resource for how to use this feature... [this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and a lot of issues linked to it might be places to start.

Comment: I think it can be simplified to `function cast<T, U>(x: Id<U> & Id<T>): T {  return x; }` without conditional types, by the way.  I'm trying to force TypeScript to recognize that two types are compatible by leading it through the exercise of checking each proprerty with `Id<>`.